# How do I use Jenkins s3 publish plugin to the same location for every build?

Tags: c#, jenkins, amazon-s3, jenkins-plugins

I am using Jenkins to build my application, which I then need to publish to s3. One of the outputs is an installation exe file that I then provide as a link to users of the application. Because of this I need this installer file to always be in the same place, for every build. However, no matter how I set up my S3 Publishing post-build step the the artifacts are uploaded to a separate folder for every build, like so
[image: s3 structure]

Is there a way for me to set up the publish to the root of the directory/bucket every time, overwriting the old file if neccesary?  This would eliminate the jobs/TestTrayApp/{buildnumber} directories. This is my s3 publish post-build step setup:

[image]

Comment: I'm currently experiencing the same issue. Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @fuzzi Unchecking "Manage artifacts" will publish to the root of the folder you specify, every build.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I fully understand what exactly what you want, but based on what I could gather up,you have an .exe file which needs to be in a particular location before publishing to s3 ?

Why not add a another post build action before your actual post build(publishing to s3) copy .exe to the destination location and then initiate publish build.

wont that be easier :)

Comment: I think that the issue is that the Destination bucket is set to "/blahblahblah", however s3 publish creates a new folder structure of blahblahblah/jobs/Test/{buildnumber}, so the files are added in these directories, rather than just in the root folder blahblahblah.

Comment: You have checked the manager artifact, so it should take the same structure as per your project build ... Can you confirm whether or not your build isn't actually creating the structure that you described. Also can you check Jenkins logs and see that it actually says that it's copying to so and so location. If it does have you tried deleting that location from s3 and try building again... This time did it actually create the folder structure from Jenkins (check the logs)

Comment: The "source" option contains only the file to be pushed to S3.  Creating a new S3 bucket from the build, adds the file with the "jobs/{job-name{/{build-number}" structure, rather than adding to the root.  The output from Jenkins is : " Publish artifacts to S3 Bucket bucket={bucket-name} "

Comment: As per what you have mentioned Jenkins is doing it's job, it's taking the file and pushing it to s3. Internally I'm not sure for s3, but it will use a scp command (transfer files across servers/system). Can you attach the log file screenshot (located from Jenkins downloaded directory ) or you'll get the log from manage Jenkins logs

Answer (score 0):

You simply need another build step that copies the published .exe artifact to the permanent location for users to download.

I think you are confusing "publishing an app to your production environment" and publishing build artifacts. I believe the intent of this Jenkins S3 publish plugin is not to be used for your final release production version but as a build step to archive build artifacts, archive might have the same meaning as publishing in this context regarding your build artifacts. [See this article](https://vnextcoder.wordpress.com/2016/10/25/part-3-storing-jenkins-output-to-aws-s3-bucket/) for why I am thinking the Jenkins S3 publish plugin is not meant to be used to actually publish the final release version of your application.

Use a Jenkins Pipeline or add another build step to your Freestyle to copy the exe from S3 build artifact archive to your final permanent storage container for users to download from your website/app.

Answer (score 0):

Unselect both `Manage artifacts` and `Flatten directories` checkboxes. And as per the `Source` give the directory name followed by a `/` which contains your executable. For example:

[image]

This way your latest executable will always be placed in `bucket/blahblahblah/executable/executable.exe` location no matter how many times your job runs.

Comment: What if we want to publish under ' bucket/blahblahblah/executable.exe ' . I am stuck in this case